# How to say: subway line is not in operation

Tags: translation

How to say in Chinese:

> Today part of the blue subway line is not in operation.

Should it be 在操作? Or another word?

Comment: `运行`, `运转`, `运营`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今天部分蓝色地铁线路中止/暂停运行。

Operation has a lot of similar meanings. But 操作 is not appropriate here since it's usually used with machines or computers. For a subway line, 运行 is much better because 行 means moving. 运营 is OK but it's usually used for companies or long term activities.

And in Chinese there is no predictive so you need to add a predicate like 停止、中止、暂停.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that operate means "操作" in Chinese. But in this context, it should be translated into:
“今天蓝色地铁线部分**停止运营**。”